# Further Congruency within the Nottingham Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, power-series, congruences, profinite-groups

> Write $A$ for the group of continuous automorphisms of $\mathbb{F}_{p}[[t]]$ and for each $n \geq 1$ let $J_{n}$ be the kernel of the homomorphism from $A$ to the automorphism group of $\mathbb{F}_{p}[[t]]/(t^{n+1})$, where $(t^{n+1})$ is the ideal generated by $t^{n+1}$.
>
> For each $n \geq 1$ let $e_{n} \in J_{n}$ be defined by $e_{n}(t) = t + t^{n+1}$. Assume for simplicity that $p \neq 2$. Prove that $[e_{r}, e_{s}] \equiv e_{r+s}^{r-s} \mod J_{r+s+1}$ for all $r, s \geq 1$. Deduce that $J_{1}$ is generated by $\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}$.

This is a continuation on my previous question, [Congruency within the Nottingham Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2227151), which shows that $J_{1}$ can be generated by $\{e_{i} \mid i \geq n\}$. I've managed to prove the first part of this exercise but I'm struggling to make the following deduction. My effort is as follows:

$[e_{n}, e_{1}] \equiv e_{n+1}^{n-1} \mod J_{n+2}$. Then we can recursively express powers of $e_{n}$ for $n \geq 3$ purely in terms of powers of $e_{1}, e_{2}$ modulo $J_{n+1}$.

I'm not really convinced by my own argument and I'm way out of my depth to be honest, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some technical details. First of all, the group $J_1$ is a profinite group, so the proper meaning of $\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ generating it is that it generates a dense subgroup. In the category of profinite groups, this means that $\{ e_1, e_2 \}$ generates all of the quotients $J_1/J_n$ for $n \geq 2$. These are all finite $p$-groups, and your recursive argument works well in this setting.